# Submit Form with ENTER key is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a `form` with drop down, text boxes and one submit button. I can submit form with `ENTER` key like just add `ng-keypress="addBookmarkOnEnter($event)` with any text boxes and it'll work.

But can I do same task without adding `ng-keypress` with any text box?

Here is my `form`:

```
<form>
   <div><input type="text" class="greyPhold" placeholder="http://" data-ng-model="bookmark.url" /></div>
   <div class="forSelect">
      <div class="selHead" data-ng-class="{hOpen: popup.dropdownStatus}">
         <button data-ng-click="toggleDropdown()"><span data-ng-bind="popup.selectedCategory"></span></button>
         <ul id="testDiv2" class="dropdownH">
            <li data-ng-repeat="category in categories track by $index" data-ng-click="selectCategory($index)">
               <div class="colony pull-left"><span>{{category.category_name}}</span></div>
               <div class="pull-right"><input type="radio" name="tag" /><label></label></div>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="createColony">
      <input type="text" class="whitePholder" placeholder="Create a new colony" data-ng-model="bookmark.categoryName"/>
   </div>
   <div class="complete text-center"><button type="submit" class="done" data-ng-click="addBookmark()">Complete</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: please make a fiddle to make it clearer.

Comment: I have dynamic content and it'll not work on 'plunker', so that I didn't give any `plunker` link

Comment: follow this: http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/05/submit-form-on-enter-click-angular-js.html

Answer (score 0):

hope this code would be help you

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="gray">
    <div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller="two_way_control" style="background-color:CCFF66">
<p style="padding:10px;">
          <h1 align="center">  Search Product </h1>
          </p>
<p align="center">
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Enter a name here" required>
        <button ng-click="check(searchText)">Search</button>
</form>
</p>
       Search Item Name:  {{searchText}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and use given code inside controller

```
$scope.check=function(searchText){};
```